# jquery toggle height and change button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this div (#world) that is 500px height as default. I also got a button with the value "open" when I click on the button the #world div should animate and decrease to a height of 200px at the same time the button value will be change to "close".

Need some help :(
I've googled this but i can't really understand how to this. Yes I'm a newbie :)

Comment: Give us a starting point. You have html at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FRBhz/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        this.value = (this.value == 'open') ? 'close' : 'open';
        var new_height = ($('#world').height() == 500) ? 200 : 500;
        $('#world').animate({
            height: new_height
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: yes, but i dont seems to work for me... which framework should I use. I use <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

Comment: do you know @letiagoalves ?

Comment: This demo uses 1.9.1 version. You can use it from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Where are you including jQuery script? It must be before your page Javascript